# Как сохранить значение ссылки

Tags: php

Добрый день профессионалы. У меня  есть ссылка, когда её нажимаешь, передается значение через переменную dep_link. Далее я использую это значение через GET

```
$_GET['dep_link']
```

Вопрос: Как мне однажды нажав ссылку, сохранить это значение для дальнейшей обработки, например кнопки? То есть логика такая - сначала я выбрал что то перейдя по ссылке, а далее мне надо использовать значение ссылки, нажав кнопку. Ведь если я нажимаю кнопку, то я не нажимаю ссылку :) и значение ссылки обнуляется и ничему не равно. Сам пока не могу справится с проблемой.

Comment: Смотрите с сторону сессий или кук, одно сохраняет значения до закрытия браузера, другое по времени.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно данные из `$_GET['dep_link']` положить в `$_SESSION['dep_link']` - эти данные будут доступны при следующем вызове скрипта. Или же использовать данные из `$_GET['dep_link']` для заполнения скрытых полей в форме, тогда при подаче формы эти данные попадут на сервер вместе с остальными.